# Creating a Win32 application for both XP and Vista/Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, manifest

I've written an application in C++ using the pure win32 api (no MFC or WPF).
I want the same .exe to run under both Window's XP and Windows Vista / Windows 7.

I was using a manifest to add Visual Styles to the controls in my application. However, when I tested the app on an XP Machine, Buttons do not show up. Only Edit controls and the Menu Bar do.

**Edit:** I think I forgot to mention this, but the application works fine on WIndows 7/Vista.
**Edit 2:** I'm using the MinGW compiler
I thought that this was a problem with the manifest, so I removed it and recompiled my program. But the buttons still don't show up.
The manifest that I am using is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version="1.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="*"
    name="BlackJack.Viraj"
    type="win32"
/>
<description>Your application description here.</description>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.2600.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
</assembly>
```

Does the problem lie in the manifest or is it something else?

Comment: Did you use the new button style with the UAC shield on it? I don't know if XP ignores unknown flags or if it's an unknown button.

Comment: No. They are all normal buttons.

Comment: Can you post the code of the button creation?

Comment: The problem was with not calling InitCommonControls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you call [InitCommonControlsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775697%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: If he doesn't even have a manifest and still has a problem, then I don't think this will help - as far as I know you don't have to call this just to create a simple button in Win32.  (Not that this isn't a good function to call!)

Comment: InitCommonControlsEx has nothing to do with the manifest. It just makes sure the common controls DLL is loaded

Comment: Yeah I know - I looked it up.  But buttons predate the very existence of the common controls DLL... I'm surprised this API call would be required if there isn't even a manifest!

Comment: Why would this make any difference? If you weren't calling this then it would fail equally in non-themed?

Comment: Not sure. I just know I've had this same problem from experience.

Answer (score 1):

It's something else.  Assuming they are the normal, standard buttons they should show up no matter what the manifest looks like, or whether or not there is one.  Something else is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using new Windows 7 API, a standard application will go well with both platform. Also Windows 7 has compatibility mode to try out if you find something broken.

Are you sure that you've called InitCommonControls API in the beginning of your program?

See why it's important - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/18/439939.aspx

I'd suggest you to refer a pure Win32 Application
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/22/410773.aspx

Also I'd suggest putting the manifest within the Linker options itself in the source file.

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_IA64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='ia64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: `#pragma comment` is, I believe, a Visual C-ism and so won't work with Mingw.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest is fine. Therefore the problem must be in your code. Creating a themed application isn't quite the same as a non-themed one.